# Third-person singular used for emphasis in online communication -- Why?

Tags: grammar, slang

I signed up simply to ask this question, although it's awfully niche.

In textual situations, such as for roleplay or for humor, on the internet, one will use the third-person singular form of a verb to express that they are the one carrying it out. The best example I can conjure of this is someone saying "*winks [at you]*" in a text message - using asterisks to imply that it is an action.

It is "he/she winks," not "I winks."

Why do we do this? Any theories?

Many thanks.

Comment: We do it to pretend it's an action, just like you said. "I'm winking at you" would imply you're really doing it and feel quite weird.

Comment: @LjL That’s probably true, but why does *winks* not feel “quite weird” but “I’m winking at you” does?

Comment: This is a style question, not a linguistics question. Textile situation? The s is for says the speaker.

Comment: I think you mean _textual_. _Textile_ is about woven (or other) fabric not about text.

Comment: I think this is a linguistics question, if a slightly unusual one.

Comment: @GrahamH. I believe that's because certain protocols and conventions that emerged on the internet made it natural. Other people have mentioned IRC, that's one clear example. Other protocols also offer "/me" functionality, so on the ones that don't, people were used to it and "added" it using their own conventions, such as asterisks. In turn, I think the reason it feels natural to have "/me" functionality in chat protocols is that the most conspicuously missing thing in text chat compared to real-life interactions is the absence of actions. Wanting to "emulate" actions is then natural.

Comment: It's most probably taken from the way theatrical plays are written in books. A l b e r t o: Hello, my dear Francesca! [_looks at his watch_] Oh!.. How short our meeting was!.. I have to leave instantly!...

Answer (score 2):

In IRC (and I imagine other early text-based messaging services), someone's online handle would usually appear immediately to the left of their message. So a message like "winks at you" would be displayed as "Draconis winks at you". (Sometimes there was a special syntax to ensure there wouldn't be a colon between the username and the message, too, specifically for things like this.)

In other words, it's third person singular to agree with the sender's username, as read by the recipient.

Comment: This was even clearer with IRC commands: `/me winks` would display: *cmw winks*.

Comment: The interesting thing is that this has been carried over (I guess?) into quite different contexts, such as inline ‘mood/action descriptors’ in asterisks, where the subject is virtually always implied. For example, something like this would be completely natural in a comment on social media: “Oh my god, I _need_ this right now \*hyperventilates\*” (with the asterisked verb in the third person singular).

Comment: That would not be my guess. It must be simply a transfer from transcribed conversations where "[laughs]" etc. traditionally appear.

Comment: @Nardog The IRC use presumably extends the earlier transcription use, but there is the fundamental difference that transcriptions are _written by someone else_, so the third person makes sense there: the transcriber is literally recording a third person’s speech/actions. In IRC and ‘asterisk’ use, the writer refers to _their own speech/actions_ in the third person, often even mixed in with normal first-person usage.

Comment: My own theory is that it's a stylistic choice. In English, "[I] wink" doesn't represent the timing we want it to (as this is strict to habitual usage, really), but "[I'm] winking" may just seem too drawn out. It's possible that we simply use the third-person form because it looks nicer: that extra S on the end. Although, Draconis' hypothesis seems reasonable. Thanks for the answer!